# Magento2: Price Formating

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0

I need to change the price format in product page, i already try to do this

```
# vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Locale/Data/vi.xml
<symbols numbersystem="latn">
 <decimal>.</decimal>
 <group>,</group>
</symbols>

# vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/PriceCurrencyInterface.php
const DEFAULT_PRECISION = 0

# vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/Currency.php
return $this->formatPrecision($price, 0, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);

# vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order.php
public function formatPrice($price, $addBrackets = false)
{
    return $this->formatPricePrecision($price, 0, $addBrackets);
}
```

And this work for most of my site. like category page & order & cart & checkout
but it wont work with product page.

can u help me with that please ?

[image: I need to change the price format.]

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a rewrite of the `\Magento\Framework\Locale\Format` class. To do this create a custom module with a di.xml file. In this file create a preference for the `\Magento\Framework\Locale\Format` class like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Locale\Format" type="Namespace\Module\Model\Locale\Format" />
</config>
```

Now in your custom module create the file you refer to `Namespace\Module\Model\Locale\Format` with this code in it:

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Module\Model\Locale;

class Format extends \Magento\Framework\Locale\Format
{
    public function getPriceFormat($localeCode = null, $currencyCode = null)
    {
        // Force the locale to create your desired price format
        $localeCode = 'nl_NL';
        return parent::getPriceFormat($localeCode, $currencyCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: There was an extension force the price to look like this .. sorry for your time bro :-)